# Yii2 DatePicker

Tags: jquery-ui, yii2

I'm running a datePicker for a date of birth field in Yii2. I'm trying to display the year also. I've checked the JQuery docs http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year and I thought I would be able to achieve this with `changeYear`. But it doesn't seem to work. What's the way to do this? This is my current code.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'date_of_birth')->widget(DatePicker::className(),[
   'name' => 'date_of_birth',
   'language' => 'en-GB',
   'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
   'options' => [
      'changeMonth' => true,
      'changeYear' => true,
      'yearRange' => '1996:2099',
      'showOn' => 'button',
      'buttonImage' => 'images/calendar.gif',
      'buttonImageOnly' => true,
      'buttonText' => 'Select date'
    ],
]) ?>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should simply use [`clientOptions`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-widget.html#$clientOptions-detail) instead of `options` :

```
'clientOptions' => [
    'changeMonth' => true,
    'yearRange' => '1996:2099',
    'changeYear' => true,
    'showOn' => 'button',
    'buttonImage' => 'images/calendar.gif',
    'buttonImageOnly' => true,
    'buttonText' => 'Select date'
],
```

Comment: Setting unknown property: kartik\date\DatePicker::clientOptions

Comment: Its same datepicker and getting above error when using clientOptions

Comment: IT IS NOT THE SAME !

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use HTML5 date type. That is so simple. You dont need to add widgets:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'date_of_birth')->textField(['type' => 'date']);?>
```

This will add the date picker.

Comment: its the better solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following codes:

```
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
    use kartik\select2\Select2;
    use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
    use kartik\date\DatePicker;
    use yii\widgets\Pjax;

     <?=$form->field($model, 'columnName')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
        'language' => 'tr',
        'value' => date('dd/mm/yyyy', strtotime('+7 days')),
        'readonly' => true,
        #'disabled' => true,
        #'size' => 'lg',
        #'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND,
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Başlangıç Tarihi Seç ...'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            #'orientation' => 'top right',
            'format' => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'todayHighlight' => true,
            'todayBtn' => true,
            'autoclose'=>true,
        ]
]);?>
```